# Get a list of available WooCommerce coupons in a select field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

As part of a plugin I am creating with the WooCommerce API, I need to get the coupons to show in the select field. Here is the relevant piece of code:

```php
// Get coupons
function coupon_list() {
    $coupon_posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'order'            => 'asc',
        'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    ) );

    $coupon_codes = []; 

    foreach( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post) {
        $coupon_codes[] = $coupon_post->post_name;
    }

    return implode($coupon_codes) ;
}

$settings = array(
    'coupon_to_use' => array(
        'name'      => __( 'Coupon to use'),
        'type'      => 'select',
        'default'   => '',
        'desc'      => __( 'Use this.'),
        'desc_tip'  => true,
        'id'        => 'the_coupon_type',
        'options'   => array(
            coupon_list(), // This is where I am stuck
        )
    )
);

return apply_filters( 'the_coupon_settings', $settings );
```

The options array should have something like this...

```php
'options'   => array(
    'coupon_1' => __( 'Coupon 1'),
    'coupon_2' => __( 'Coupon 2'),
)
```

..but `coupon_list()` is just returning a string of coupon names. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function  doesn't return an array, but a string
by the use of `implode()` and you should use `$coupon_post->post_name` for the array keys:

```php
function coupon_list() {
    $coupon_posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'order'            => 'asc',
        'post_type'        => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
    ) );

    $coupon_codes = []; // Initializing

    // Push to array
    foreach ( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post ) {
        $coupon_codes[$coupon_post->post_name] = $coupon_post->post_title;
    }

    // Return coupon array
    return $coupon_codes;
}
```

---

In WooCommerce you can then use  `woocommerce_form_field()` - ( `type' => 'select'` ) to create a drop-down list (frontend) - for the backend you can use `woocommerce_wp_select()`.

For example to display this on the WooCommerce single product page (frontend), you can use:

```php
function action_woocommerce_single_product_summary() {
    // Add select field
    woocommerce_form_field( 'the_coupon_type', array(
        'type'      => 'select',
        'label'     => __( 'Coupon to use', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'  => false,
        'options'   => coupon_list(),
    ),'' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_summary', 9 );
```

Comment: We can use this simple query to get an array of coupons                                              
  `global $wpdb;
   $coupon_codes_arr = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT LOWER(post_title) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'shop_coupon'");`